# Android mobile first app stopped working after Bluemix moved to cflinuxfs2 stack

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

I have an android app based on the bluelist app for bluemix BMS service. it stopped working yesterday when the stack is moved to cflinuxfs2.
Today I checked my ios app on the same bluemix service, it is working. so I looked into the exception on Android, it is from MFPush, looks like a context is null. see the attached image for the line of code where the NPE is thrown.[image]
The stacktrace is: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Context.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)' on a null object reference
12-10 16:00:31.240 14482-14482/com.ibm.bluelist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPush.listen(MFPPush.java:232)
12-10 16:00:31.240 14482-14482/com.ibm.bluelist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ibm.bluelist.GroupsActivity.onResume(GroupsActivity.java:250)
12-10 16:00:31.240 14482-14482/com.ibm.bluelist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
12-10 16:00:31.240 14482-14482/com.ibm.bluelist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6119)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are the MFPPush SDK has not been initialized when you are attempting to call: 
`push.listen(notificationListener)`

I suggest saving the push value:
`push = MFPPush.getInstance()`
Immediately after initialization or registration (whatever you feel is more appropriate) in the class.

That way you will have the appropriate initialized `push` instance when attempting to listen to a notification listener.